# Move title into left margin and align with first line of paragraph

Tags: spacing, sectioning, alignment

I want to move title of section left by the following code. However, it fails to move the section number. Why and how to deal with it?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\section{\makebox[0pt][r]{my section}}|main body
\end{document}
```

**EDIT**:
I want to 
move title of section into left margin of page. Meanwhile, the first line of paragraph aligns with the title(not below title as usual), as shown on the following picture.
Is there such a method?
[image]

Comment: Short and sneaky: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\textcolor{white}{
\section{\makebox[0pt][r]{\textcolor{black}{\protect\thesection~my section}}}
}
|main body
\end{document}`

Comment: Thank you @marnot for your trick to handle the section number and shield the original one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple using titlesec:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\begin{document}
\section{Old section}
\titleformat{\section}% Change section style
{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}% font (normal)
{\hspace{-5em}\thesection}% Label - add some negative horizontal space before
{1em}% Space between label and title
{}% Additional code (unused)
\section{New section}
\end{document}
```

Output:
[image: output]

Comment: I add the optional arg `[leftmargin]` in your code(and remove `\hspace{-5em}`), but the title seems not in left margin, and only one word per line in the title of section, why and how to do?

Comment: I believe this puts the entire title in the margin. So you're seeing 'one word per line' because that's all that will fit in the margin. Hence why I didn't use that optional argument.

Comment: And is there such a way to put the first line of paragraph  in the same line with section title?

Comment: Yes, the runin predefined format (instead of leftmargin)

Comment: As the length of title is not constant, is there a better way other than `\hspace{-5em}' to put all title in left margin, meanwhile, its related paragraph has the same effect of `runin` and `hang`? I mean, all content of title is in left margin, first line of para is on the same line of title

Comment: I would recommend reading the titlesec documentation and then only posting another question if you need further help.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `adjustwidth` environment from the `changepage` package to move the section.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{changepage}
\begin{document}
    \begin{adjustwidth}{-2cm}{0pt}
    \section{my section}
    \end{adjustwidth}
    | main body
\end{document}
```